# Replace an element if it has the same value, PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to replace an element or an image or a button that has the same value.

I have two tables `charts` and `legends`:

In `charts` there is an `id` and `Description`

[image]

In `legends` there is `id` , `chart_status` and  `chart_id`

[image]

So if the status is `1` then the element must replace the element

I tried joining the legends and charts but the result I get is only 1 element and the other elements are not shown.

How can I achieve this? I am looking for something like this: please see this image
[image]

But on my end I am seeing this:

[image]

Here is my view:

```
<?php foreach($status as $chart): ?>

            
    <?php if($chart['chart_status'] == 0): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><?php echo $chart['chart_id'] ?></a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($chart['chart_status'] == 1): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><?php echo $chart['chart_id'] ?></a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php foreach($charts as $chart): ?>
    
      <?php if($chart['status'] == 0): ?>
      <tr>
           <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
      </tr>
     <?php endif; ?>

     <?php if($chart['status'] == 1): ?>
     <tr>
         <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
     </tr>
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller

```
 public function index(){
     $data['charts'] = $this->chart_model->get_charts();
     $data['status'] = $this->chart_model->get_legends();

     $this->load->view('charts', $data);
    
    }

    public function view($id){

     $data['id'] = $id;

     $data['chart'] = $this->chart_model->get_chart($id);
        
     $this->load->view('view', $data);
    
    }

    public function save(){
        $this->chart_model->save();

        redirect('/');
    }
```

Model

```
public function get_charts(){
    $query = $this->db->get('charts');
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_legends(){
    $query = $this->db->get('legends');
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_chart($id){
    $query = $this->db->get('charts');
    return $query->row_array();
}


public function save(){
        
        $data = array(
            'chart_id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'chart_status' => 1
        );

        return $this->db->insert('legends', $data);
}
```

Comment: You can use join to combine the result and then show the data accordingly

Comment: @sauhardnc - hello, I tried using the join but I get only `1` then the other numbers are not shown. can you please show an example of you join? I join the charts `charts.id` and the `legends.chart_id` but i get only 1 number

Comment: You might be using inner join, try using left or right (whichever suits your needs)

Comment: @sauhardnc tried both but still indeed not getting the expected output.

Comment: Ok then share the table structure with some data in the question so I can take a look at them.

Comment: @sauhardnc okay sure, I will screen shot the two tables here

Comment: @sauhardnc - please see table above, thank you good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller index method

```
public function index()
{
    $data['charts'] = $this->chart_model->get_charts();
    $statuses = $this->chart_model->get_legends();
    $data['status'] = [];
    foreach ($statuses as $status) {
        $data['status'][$status['chart_id']] = $status['chart_status'];
    }
    $this->load->view('charts', $data);

}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($charts as $chart): ?>

    <?php if(isset($status[$chart['id']]) && $status[$chart['id']] == 1): ?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
        </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or Model method get_charts

**I may be wrong, I didn't work with codeigniter

```
public function get_charts(){
    $this->db->select('charts.*,legends.chart_status');
    $this->db->join('legends', 'legends.chart_id = charts.id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get('charts');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And view

```
<?php foreach($charts as $chart): ?>

    <?php if($chart['chart_status'] == 1): ?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
        </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/view/<?php echo $chart['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><?php echo $chart['id'] ?></a></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain? I don't know why but it works, why the first foreach was removedD?

Comment: In fact, you need to make the left join of the legends table to the charts table, so it will be more correct. In the current version, I put the charts statuses in the $status array of the form ['chart_id'=> 'chart_status'], and in the form just checked if this entry from the chart () table has status==1

Comment: Look at the extension of the response, if I am not mistaken, you will not need to execute the get_legends method at all

Comment: I tried the left join but it gives an unknown number and unknown ids. so it does not work